# Forcefully Logout user from frontend in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-admin, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am using **React** for frontend and **Django** for the backend. I have created a button **"Force logout"** in django admin for each use on click of which I want to logout the user working on the frontend (when he refresh he should be logged out). I want to do this completely in django without touching Reach. I am using `djangorestframework-simplejwt` for authentication.

Comment: Without wanting to do much self-promotion, I made a small package for this: https://github.com/hapytex/django-single-session/ the idea is to make a table that maps sessions on users. Logging out then just removes the session(s) of the user.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it's like storing new session data for a specific username and removing existing session data for that same username?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I tried your suggestion but it didn't work for me.

Comment: you want list of active sessions in your admin panel with logout button for every user which are logged in somewhere? and if you do logout from you admin panel that user should be logged out from his/her device right is that what you want?

Comment: You will have to store generated tokens and login data (such as location, device name) in separate table, and add an admin panel with an action to blacklist needed tokens. [Simple JWT blacklist app](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blacklist_app.html)

Comment: @HemalPatel  @Ersain I am using ```djangorestframework-simplejwt``` for authentication, say when user login they get the refresh and access token. even if i clear the session they can still get the data through API as they has access token. also every-time the user login they get new refresh and access token every-time and same cannot be stored for the security reason and hence cannot retrieved current access token to blacklist.

Comment: @IbrahimKhan: can you explain what went wrong. It might be useful to look if the package can be "harmonized" in some way.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem we have set the access token to expire after 24 hours from the time it is generated. Say a user logged in through API he gets the access token and refresh token which is valid for 24 hours and he can do the API calls within that time frame **Even if the sessions are cleared from the database.** After clearing the session I tried to do API call with same access token and It still works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Maybe there is a better way. Create a table suppose `AuthSession` to store session data. fields `username` and `session_key`. whenever anyone do login. add those two field values to that New table. delete old from `AuthSession`if same username is in it. Than you can do normal table data listing in admin panel as you do for regular tables. Whichever session you want to do `Force logout` You already have it's Session key. delete it from table `from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session` like this `Session.objects.filter(session_key=key).delete()` and that user will get logout from his device.
But you have to use stronghold middleware to keep your app login required all the time

Comment: I am using ```djangorestframework-simplejwt``` for authentication, say when user login they get the refresh and access token. even if i clear the session they can still get the data through API as they has access token. also every-time the user login they get new refresh and access token every-time and same cannot be stored for the security reason and hence cannot retrieved current access token to blacklist.

Comment: @IbrahimKhan is it on git? share if its for learning purpose.

Comment: No it is not on github we are using bitbucket and it is realtime project and hence can't share.

Comment: @IbrahimKhan um okay.  Then I'm not sure I have to set up this test case to do this. will and let you know if I can.